# Jest test throws "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" when tested action returns a call to fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, fetch

I'm trying to debug a Jest test in a React/Redux app; I'm running the following test (I haven't implemented faker yet).

```
it("Should create a SUBMIT_CONTACT_ME_FORM_SUCCESS action when contact me form submission completes successfully.", () => {
    const contactMe = {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Shepard",
        email: "shepard@n7.gov",
        comments: "I am not the very model of a scientist salarian."
    };
    fetchMock.postOnce(contactMeURL, {
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
        body: contactMe
    });
    const expectedActions = [
        {
            type: navbarActions.SUBMIT_CONTACT_ME_FORM_REQUEST,
            contactMeForm
        },
        {
            type: navbarActions.SUBMIT_CONTACT_ME_FORM_SUCCESS,
            contactMe,
            receivedAt: 1
        }
    ;
    const store = mockStore({ contactMe: null });
    return store.dispatch(navbarActions.submitContactMeForm(contactMeForm, 1))
        .then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });
});
```

However, my logs point to the beginning of the fetch in the following statement within the tested action.

```
    return fetch(`${apiRoot}/contact`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(contactMeForm)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            if (json.err) {
                dispatch(submitContactMeFormFailure(json.err, forcedTime))
            } else {
                dispatch(submitContactMeFormSuccess(json, forcedTime))
            }
        });
```

It seems to be a timing/lifecycle issue, but I can't isolate or correct it. I'm using the following dev dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "fetch-mock": "^9.11.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.9.0",
    "jasmine-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer but try running your test with `async`

```
it("Should ... successfully.", async() => {
    const contactMe = {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Shepard",
        email: "shepard@n7.gov",
        comments: "I am not the very model of a scientist salarian."
    };

    fetchMock.postOnce(contactMeURL, {
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
        body: contactMe
    });

    const expectedActions = [
        {
            type: navbarActions.SUBMIT_CONTACT_ME_FORM_REQUEST,
            contactMeForm
        },
        {
            type: navbarActions.SUBMIT_CONTACT_ME_FORM_SUCCESS,
            contactMe,
            receivedAt: 1
        };

    const store = mockStore({ contactMe: null });
  
    await store.dispatch(navbarActions.submitContactMeForm(contactMeForm, 1));

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
});
```